# Is it possible to query order by on a number stored as string in the database to get data as numbers in descending order

Tags: mysql, select

i have stored some number in the form of string in the database now i wants to retrieve them in descending order as numbers from database can i do this and how can i achieve this

```
select * from article order by numbers DESC
```

it result the order of number as

```
90
89
88
1000
10
1
```

Comment: Store them as a numeric data type not strings data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to select them individually, you just need to specify the ORDER BY part as a number.

```
SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY CAST(numbers AS SIGNED) DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're storing the numbers as varchar. Not numeric. They are sorting as strings

```
SELECT numbers 
FROM article 
ORDER BY CAST(numbers AS INT) DESC;
```

If they're numbers, store them as such. You'll also be unable to optimise this sort with an index because of the CAST

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify your exact columns so that SQL can use the `CAST()` function where you require conversion.

```
SELECT CAST(numbers AS INT) FROM article ORDER BY numbers DESC
```

This will return the numbers in correct sequence instead of an alphabetical sort.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "String" you mean "VARCHAR". Using INT and storing numbers as numbers will save you a lot of trouble.

If you really can't avoid storing these numbers that way, you could always pad them with zeroes to a certain size so they are returned in the correct order.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from article order by numbers DESC
```

There are 2 options: DESC(ending) and ASC(ending) (ASC is default).

Comment: The question asks about converting strings to numbers. He already has DESC in his original post.

Comment: He has now, he did not have that before ;-). Also, sorting on a string containing numbers and on a number should give the same result.

Comment: It doesn't. As the OP stated, it is sorting the numbers as strings, not as numbers. When sorting them as strings in descending order, 90 comes before 100 (because comparing the first characters, like in string sorting, 9 > 1). That's why you have to cast them as numbers.

Comment: @Travesty3 please dont downvote him he is right i was not having DESC before i edited it later to make question more appropriate other solutions are not working for me except Travesty3 gives me the exact result  i m storing mobile nos as string shall go for any other datatype for this. :-) thanks for your precious time

Comment: @spiderman: I can't take back my downvote unless the question is edited. JNDPNT: If you want to edit the question in some way, I can take it back. However, I still stand by the fact that the original question presented a problem with sorting strings vs. sorting numbers. ASC vs. DESC is irrelevant. If it's not in the right order one way, it won't be in the right order the other way. It seemed clear that this was the problem in the original post, unless that was also reworded before I read it.

Comment: @Travesty3 i have done a bit editing now i believe you can take your down vote back i have lost my two accounts because of down vote and that's why knows what a down vote can cause thanks for being kind

Comment: I do not mind if he keeps the downvote as I did not know SQL would sort like 90 comes before 100. However, I must admit that it really isn't motivating to put time into helping people when you are always downvoted when you misinterpreted a question or made a mistake.

Comment: @spiderman: I mis-typed that. This **answer** needs to be edited for me to take back my downvote. Perhaps my downvoting judgment isn't the greatest. My apologies.